# How to create RDS read replica in public subnet of my RDS which is in private subnet?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication, amazon-aurora

I have at RDS which is Aurora PostgreSQL and in private subnet with no to publically accessible.
Now I want to create its read replica in public subnet in same region or in cross region.
I tried to replicate in same region i.e putting read-replica to public subnet and the main one in private subnet,But did not work and read replica was in private subnet only.
Thought of replicating in cross-region but as its Aurora PostgreSQL i think there is no feature for this.

Making read replica in public subnet is important as one of a SAAS platform has to access the RDS.
As my main RDS is in private subnet whitelisting in security group and in NACL of private subnet did not work.

Also I was not able to find cross-region replica for Aurora PostgreSQL.If its there can you mention the steps.

and will it replicate my private subnet RDS to cross-region with read-replica in public subnet.

Tried creating read replica in same region but not able to change the subnet from private to public of only read replica RDS.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you really don't want to put your RDS Read Replica in a public subnet. Having your data layer private is definitely the best practice. Common pattern would be to deploy your Read replica in a private subnet in a different Availability Zone than the original one, and then, make the SaaS platform access the database via an API Call using AWS Lambda to gather the data.

Example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-lambda-tutorial.html (you can do SQS or not depending on use case).